# WPF Buttons not displaying images

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, xaml

I have a strange phenomenon happening with my buttons, in my visual studio when creating a toolbar and assigning the buttons as images to the toolbar they show in the editor, but when i run the app the buttons don't show, this is illustrated below along with the code:

Image from visual studios
[image: Image from visual studios]

Running app image
[image: Running app image]

Code:

```
 <ToolBarTray DockPanel.Dock="Top">
            <ToolBar>
                <Button ToolTip="Open">
                    <Image Source="Icons/folder_page.png" />
                </Button>
                <Button ToolTip="Save">
                    <Image Source="Icons/page_save.png" />
                </Button>
            </ToolBar>
    </ToolBarTray>
```

Answer (score 3):

Do you copy your Images to the output-directory?

Have you set the Build-Action for the Images to Content and the Copy to Output Directory to 'Copy if newer'

Comment: i added a folder in visual studios called Icons then i copied those two images to the Icons folder

Comment: Than you have to open the properties of the images and set the two properties I mentioned above

Comment: sorted it in the answer below

Answer (score 0):

By adding the images to the project they now display as a resource